# All beans fail autowire on startup because of a NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring

After upgrading my project to Spring AOP 4.3.7 I get this error trace on every bean auto-wire at Spring Boot startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationContext.java:494)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessAfterInitialization(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
...Stack truncated here for privacy reasons...
```

I get the sense this is a mismatch in a Spring AOP Jar somewhere in the stack, but cannot find anything that references an actual object to trace.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by upgrading to Spring AOP 4.3.13

See these links for the [old](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils.html) and [new](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils.html) versions of these libraries in the API.